# facebook app review for mange page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are creating an app that take content from school mobile app and upload to school Facebook page.
 1. School owner who owns the school facebook page make us(our facebook user account) as the editor of their facebook page.
 2. Now our facebook account had permission to post on their page.
 3. we create an app on developers.facebook.com using our FB account
 4. Now i had 5 school as our company client. all of those school authorize their Fb page by assigning our FB account as their page editor.
 5. Now question is do i need to pass my app for app review. since technically for posing to others pages we need ( FB manage page, publish page permission) , and hence FB ask for app review submission. But since our FB account is already editor of school page.

Does our FB app still need to go through the FB review process. and if we avoid FB review process, will FB block our account?

Here is the text from FB page:
If your app requests this permission(manage page permission) Facebook will have to review how your app uses it. You can grant this permission on behalf of people listed within the Roles section of your App's Dashboard without review by Facebook

I think only person who is mentioned in the app role section is our FB account owner. and he is the editor of 5 schools individual page. so i think we are ok. But want to take expert suggestion here.

Is their FB email where i can ask this question?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: As long as it is being used by a limited number of people (clients) you don't need your app to be reviewed.